# Reducing Google Analytics API Usage

Tags: javascript, rest, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I use the Analytics Real Time Reporting API to pull the top stories on my employer's website each hour to put in a trending items module on our homepage. For the last several weeks I've been getting emails from Google saying:

> 8.65% of the requests resulted in rateLimitExceeded or userRateLimitExceeded error. This error means that your project is hitting the QPS limit. Lowering the frequency of the calls to the Analytics API will reduce the number of errors and save daily quota.

The odd thing is, as far as I know, my app should only be making one call per hour, as I store the response in Redis and reference the cached data until it expires. And the stats from the Google API Dashboard would seem to reflect this ([Screencap from GA Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuMDn.png)).

I also added exponential backoff, as a prior email from Google had recommended, to ensure I wasn't retrying too frequently after a request fails:

```
const params = {
  'auth':        jwtClient,
  'ids':         process.env.GA_ID,
  'metrics':     'rt:pageViews',
  'dimensions':  'rt:pagePath',
  'max-results': '50',
  'sort':        '-rt:pageViews',
  'key':         process.env.GA_KEY
}

function fetchTrending() {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    jwtClient.authorize(err => { if (err) { reject(err) } })

    const getAnalytics = backoff.call(analytics.data.realtime.get, params, (error, body) => {
      if (body != null && error == null) {
        resolve(body)
      } else {
        reject(error)
      }
    })

    getAnalytics
      .retryIf(err => { return err.status == 503 })
      .setStrategy(new backoff.ExponentialStrategy())
      .failAfter(10)
      .start()
  })
}

function trending () {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    cache('gaData', 3600, () => {
      return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        fetchTrending()
          .then(gaData => {
            resolve(gaData)
          }).catch(error => {
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    })
[etc.]
```

The caching script basically says, check whether the key is present in Redis and if it is, return that data, otherwise, execute the passed function.

So, why would I be hitting Google's API limits with so few requests? And what can I do to mitigate this problem so that I reduce my "unauthorized" error rate?

Comment: Add some logging to your call to make sure what ever is running this isnt calling it more then once.

Comment: I can verify from my logs that it is not being called more than once.